# Is there a simple way to install the same Python libraries that I have in one environment to a new Python environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I want to duplicate my Python development station. I need to be able to install, with pip, the same libraries that were installed on the original station.
Is there a simple way to that instead of going into the **pip list** and installing all the libraries one by one ?

The Main purpose is to be able to duplicate the same environment that I have in one station to another station with minimum overhead. I won't like to be required to track the existence or absence of the libraries by myself

Comment: You should use virtual environments.

Comment: I second @hop .  You might also want to take a look at docker containers.

Comment: If under linux then `$ pip freeze > requirements.txt` and then `$ pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: this is now the officially recommended tool: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv

Comment: If you are using pycharm ==> change the interpreter and then select from conda package install which libs you want to install.

Answer (score 2):

1.(On virtual enviroment) Save libraries and versions

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

2. Install on new enviroment

```
pip install -r <path of requirements.txt>
```

Comment: What if I don't have a virtual environment ? Will "pip freeze" function the same ?

Comment: @MosheS. if you don't have a virtual environment, all the python libraries on your pc will saved on requirements.txt

Comment: You mean all the Python libraries that were installed by pip. Right ?

Comment: All python libraries, not necessarily just those installed with pip

Comment: Just to help others, I found out that the freeze created the requirements only for the list of libraries that were installed with pip.